# My web site automatically sends ajax request same page

Tags: php, ajax

My website sends an ajax request to the same page on every page requested. It doesn't matter what page it is. Even though I have removed all PHP / HTML / CSS / JS code, it still does this. What's the problem here?

[Site URL: mysite.com/kategori](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd3eE.png)

(Question translated by Google Translate, sorry for unclean words)

Thanks.

Comment: That request is not an ajax request, but your actual browser request. You should see that on every website, on every page. It is not a problem, but expected behavior.

Comment: @code-a1 Yeah, I tried.

Comment: @rickdenhaan OK, but CSRF Token are created 2 times. I thought it was making requests 2 times at the same time. What could be the problem here?

Comment: That is impossible to say, we'd need to see the code that creates the CSRF token. But the request of type "document" you see in your network inspector is your browser's initial request to retrieve the requested URL. Even if your website is completely down, you will still see *that* request with an error code.